# Add point name and style point layer C# NetTopo DotSpatial

Tags: c#, dotspatial, nettopologysuite

How can I add point name and style? The point layer as blue and ellipse. My code is below:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < featureCollection.Count; i++)
        {

            List<Coordinate> coordinatestext = new List<Coordinate>();
            string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, $"R_Line_{100 + i + 1}.txt");
            string textfileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(outputFilePath);

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(outputFilePath))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] parts = line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    var pn = parts[0];
                    double x = double.Parse(parts[1]);
                    double y = double.Parse(parts[2]);
                    Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(x, y);
                    coordinatestext.Add(coordinate);
                }
            }

            FeatureSet featureSet = new FeatureSet(FeatureType.Point);
            featureSet.DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
            featureSet.Name = textfileName;

            foreach (Coordinate coordinate in coordinatestext)
            {
                //  NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate testpointcoordinates = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate(x, y);

                NetTopologySuite.Geometries.GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.GeometryFactory();

                NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point textpointPoint = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(coordinate);

                featureSet.AddFeature(textpointPoint);
                var currentMapProjection = form1Instance.map1.Projection;
                featureSet.Projection = currentMapProjection;

            }

            form1Instance.map1.Layers.Add(featureSet);
            form1Instance.map1.ZoomToMaxExtent();
            form1Instance.map1.Refresh();

        }
```